# Azure SQL UserTokenCaches works locally but not deployed

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

I am authenticating using Azure AD.  I can get the the point where users can sign in with their credentials but when i go to pull the User Token to send it to the Graph API to authenticate it says it can't find my token.  The strange thing is that locally i have my  ApplicationDbContext pointing to a database in Azure SQL and it has no problem updating the UserTokenCaches table but once i deploy to my web app it no longer seems to find the database and the UserTokenCaches table never updates.

Here is what method i have narrowed it down too.  when it calls db.UserTokenCacheList for some reason locally it can connect to Azure SQL but when deployed to Azure Web app it no longer can.

```
    public ADALTokenCache(string signedInUserId)
    {
        // Associate the cache to the current user of the web app
        userId = signedInUserId;
        this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
        this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
        this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;
        // Look up the entry in the database
        Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
        // Place the entry in memory
        this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits,"ADALCache"));
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any web.config transformations that are changing your web.config?  Is your Azure SQL database configured to allow connections from within Azure?

Comment: Download the sample project from the following URL and compare it with yours. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/11/30/azure-samples-for-azure-ad-net-webapi-using-azure-ad-on-behalf-of-token-to-connect-to-sql-db-and-sql-dw/